# Undefined control sequence error \end{split}

Tags: equations

I tried to split an equation, such that it alligns under the = sign. I get an error message using this code. Could someone tell me what's wrong?

> Undefined control sequence. `<argument>` ...it@tag \begin {split} TCU &
>   = \fraq 
>                                                     {\text {purchasing cost} +... l.53 \end{split}

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
TCU & = \fraq{\text{purchasing cost} +\text{setup cost} + \text{holding cost}}{time} \\
    & = \fraq{cy+K+h\fraq{y}{2}t_0}{t_0} 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: It should be `\frac` not `\fraq` ...

Comment: and make sure to load `amsmath`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is due to a typo in a command name

Answer (score 4):

As I said in comment, for fraction is correct command `\frac`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

    \begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
TCU & = \frac{\text{purchasing cost} + \text{setup cost} + \text{holding cost}}{time} \\
    & = \frac{cy+K+h\frac{y}{2}t_0}{t_0}
\end{split}
\end{equation}    
    \end{document}
```

[image]

The fraction in numerator in the second equation line looks to small (to my taste, so for it I suggest to use `\dfrac`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

    \begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
TCU & = \frac{\text{purchasing cost} + \text{setup cost} + \text{holding cost}}{time} \\
    & = \frac{cy+K+h\dfrac{y}{2}t_0}{t_0}
\end{split}
\end{equation}    
    \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: @egreg, with this answer I have a lot of "fun". All what can go wrong with loading correct picture and only one answer, was going wrong. Hopefully now I succeed to correct all mess :-(